# NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData seems to fail randomly

Tags: ios, nsurl

My app is an image viewer for iOS. I allow users to pick files from the camera roll or cloud file providers. For each file chosen, I create a bookmark so that the user to come back to view the file later without having to go through all of the steps of the camera roll/cloud file pickers again. The camera roll bookmarks work consistently, but the cloud file provider bookmarks fail randomly by returning nil from the call to `URLByResolvingBookmarkData`. The error returned is:

> > **"File Not Found"**

This happens with files from iCloud, DropBox, Box, Google Drive, etc. Here is how I create and retrieve the bookmarks:

```
// bookmark created from url returned by UIDocumentPickerViewController
NSData *bookmark = [url bookmarkDataWithOptions:options includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil relativeToURL:url error: nil];

// retrieving the URL from this bookmark works for a short time, then returns nil
url = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:bookmark options:NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithoutUI relativeToURL:nil bookmarkDataIsStale:&isStale error:&error];
```

Anyone can shed some light as to why a bookmark will work for a while, then fail? Limited storage/RAM?

I have a feeling that the answer is to keep a local copy of files from cloud storage since they're not guaranteed to be accessible more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`startAccessingSecurityScopedResource`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417051-startaccessingsecurityscopedreso) on the URL, making sure to call [`stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1413736-stopaccessingsecurityscopedresou) when you are finished.

Alternatively, Apple highly recommend using FileCoordinator or UIDocument to manage access to files. Especially now you may access files that other apps are also accessing.

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried (this is quite a while ago). I believe it didn't work as expected. I need to test it again on the latest iOS.